# load and unload form as a string passed to a sub

Tags: vba

hi I would like to load and unload a user form by calling formtimer with a string as the form name
not sure how I would go about it ,i would love some input

```
Public Sub callme()
    
    FormTimer ("UserForm1")
    
End Sub

public Sub FormTimer(Fname As String)
    Fname.Show vbModeless
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "UnloadIt(Fname)"
    
End Sub

Public Sub UnloadIt(name As string)
    
    Unload name
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
Public Sub callme()
    
    FormTimer "UserForm1"
    
End Sub

Public Sub FormTimer(Fname As String)

    VBA.UserForms.Add(Fname).Show vbModeless
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'UnloadIt """ & Fname & """'"

End Sub

Public Sub UnloadIt(name As String)
    
    Dim uf As Object
    For Each uf In VBA.UserForms
        If uf.name = name Then
            Unload uf
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next uf
    
End Sub
```